# java - get certain parts of JSONNode / JSON

Tags: java, json, highcharts, weka

i'm new in JSON topic. 
i have a JSONNode which i get from weka's Instances. here is a slice of the JSON.

```
"data" : [
    {
        "sparse" : false,
        "weight" : 1.0,
        "values" : [
            "'11:51:33 18/05/1995'",
            "120",
            "77",
            "77",
            "19",
            "99"
        ]
    },
    {
        "sparse" : false,
        "weight" : 1.0,
        "values" : [
            "'11:51:34 18/05/1995'",
            "120",
            "77",
            "76",
            "19",
            "99"
        ]
    },
```

i need to make some JSON file from this one JSON with this format.

```
1st json
[11:51:33 18/05/1995, 120],
[11:51:34 18/05/1995, 120],
...

2nd json
[11:51:33 18/05/1995, 77],
[11:51:34 18/05/1995, 77],
...
```

3rd, 4th, and 5th json with the same format but different value on second index on each row. 
i use java with weka library. i need this to make a highchart charts like this http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare.

any idea how to get it done? thank you

Comment: what json library are you using?  BTW, the outputted *json* is not properly formed json

Comment: i just use the JSONNode from weka library.

Comment: i need to make json like this  [link](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json)

Comment: You may use JSONNode constructor to initiate your new json container and try to user weka method for adding the json as per your logic. 
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/json/JSONNode.html